# How to pass data to another controller in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the http request data from a factory, process data in a parent controller and pass back to factory for my child controller to access it.

I have something like

parent controller

```
  myFactory.makeApi(id)
            .then(function(data) {
                //process data here...
                //I want to pass productDetail back to my factory and let 
                //my child controller use it 
                $scope.productDetail    = productDetail;
            })
```

Child controller

```
//I want to get the productDetail through parent' $scope.productDetail.
//but not sure how to get it.
 myFactory.getProductDetail ???
```

myFactory

```
  service.makeApi = function(id) {      
        return getProduct(id)
            .then(function(httpObj) {
                return httpObj.data;
            })

    }

  var getProduct = function(id) {
       return $http.post('/api/product/getProduct/' + id) 
  }
```

Basically I am not sure how to pass the productDetail to my child controller. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from parent controller you can broadcast an datrecieved event  like

```
  $scope.broadcast("datarecieved", data);
```

in child you can recived this data

```
  $scope.$on("datarecieved",function(data){
  //do something 
 })
```

In your case yo can do this

Parent Code

```
        myFactory.makeApi(id)
        .then(function(data) {
            //process data here...
            //I want to pass productDetail back to my factory and let 
            //my child controller use it 
            $scope.productDetail    = productDetail
            $scope.broadcast("datarecieved", productDetail);
        })
```

in child

```
   $scope.$on("datarecieved",function(data){
     //do something 
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

By parent and child controller, I assume you mean that their views are nested.

If that is the case, the child `$scope`prototypally inherits from the parent `$scope`, so you can retrieve it in the child controller with `$scope.productDetail`.